# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: option is not a supported field type

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jira-rest-api

Using the following library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.rcarz</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting error while executing below code:

```
BasicCredentials creds = new BasicCredentials("username", "password");
JiraClient jira = new JiraClient("xyz/rest/api/2/issue", creds);

Issue newIssue = jira.createIssue("XYZ", "Bug")
           .field(Field.SUMMARY, "tEST bUG")
           .field("customfield_20200","No STeps")
           .field("customfield_20202","No actual")
           .field("customfield_25600",Field.valueById("35650"))
            .execute();
```

Getting error for `field("customfield_25600",Field.valueByID("35650"))`

Error Description :

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: option is not a supported
>   field type

This is customized field in JIRA.

Please let me know if required more information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it normal you have 2 dots in `Field..valueByID("35650")`?

Comment: Sorry it was bymistake i put here

Comment: Issue newIssue = jira.createIssue("XYZ", "Bug")
      .field(Field.SUMMARY, "tEST bUG")
      .field("customfield_20200","No STeps")
      .field("customfield_20202","No actual")
      .field("customfield_25600",Field.valueById("35650"))
       .execute();

Comment: Please edit your original post to remove the double dots. It is more visible than in the comments section

Comment: What is the return type of `Field.valueByID` ?

Comment: it returns field. For example, It is working fine for customfield which has text fields with .field("custom_field","value") but when it comes to drop down custom field it wont work

Comment: Also for people like me not familiar with the Jira library, what is the type of your `jira` variable?

Comment: Ok. I am raising defect when my test scenario gets failed in selenium automation nad I am calling JIRA REST api for this. BasicCredentials creds = new BasicCredentials("username", "password");

JiraClient jira= new JiraClient("https://xyz/rest/api/2/issue", creds);

Comment: What library are you using? I can't find this `JiraClient` object

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>net.rcarz</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>

Comment: The code you provide throws the following error when I run it. 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.

Comment: yes. because i remove the project details. I can not share project details in public

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a known issue with the library,the field you try to add is probably an `option` and it is not supported

The error was already reported here:

https://github.com/rcarz/jira-client/issues/123

> Hi,
>
> trying to use custom fields, I encounter the following issue :
>   For a "Select List (single choice)" type of field, I get the following exception when trying to create an issue :
>   Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: option is not a supported field type
>   at net.rcarz.jiraclient.Field.toJson(Field.java:655)
>   at net.rcarz.jiraclient.Issue$FluentCreate.executeCreate(Issue.java:104)
>   at net.rcarz.jiraclient.Issue$FluentCreate.execute(Issue.java:59)
>
> I'm using JIRA v7.1.0-OD-05-006

It seems to have to do with the JIRA version.

Following the link to #154, it seems that it was not fixed.

https://github.com/rcarz/jira-client/pull/154

> The issue still persists
>
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: option is not a supported field type
>   at net.rcarz.jiraclient.Field.toJson(Field.java:737)
>   at net.rcarz.jiraclient.Issue$FluentCreate.executeCreate(Issue.java:102)
>   at net.rcarz.jiraclient.Issue$FluentCreate.execute(Issue.java:57)
>
> Here is my snippet code looks like. The customfield_12133 is an options.
>
> JiraClient jiraClient;
>   Issue issue = jiraClient.createIssue("MYPROJECT", "Internal Bug")
>   .field(Field.SUMMARY, summary)
>   .field(Field.DESCRIPTION, summary)
>   .field("customfield_12133", "Other")
>   .execute();

Finally pull #176 should actually have fixed it:

https://github.com/rcarz/jira-client/pull/176

might be fixed in the next version (0.6) of the library

Comment: I added a bit, fix 176 should fix it actually. So not sure what is going on

Answer (score 0):

`Field#toJson()` method had not know about option type in v0.5, it was added later. That is why method throws `UnsupportedOperationException`. Try to use the latest version from GitHub: https://github.com/rcarz/jira-client

Comment: could u plz explain little more because when i am changing to 0.6 it is not allowing me to use existing code

Comment: @Shashi v0.6 was not released and is absent in maven repo.